# service, threading and networking

Tags: android-service, android-networking

I have been reading about services, executor, handler and I am still confused.
I want a Thread to handle websocket protocol. I want any Activity to be able to use it to send a "command" and receive a reply to a callback. Each command will use a separate thread for network activity but use this websocket thread at the manager and initial reply handling.

[Send Cmd]: AnyActivity -> WebSocketThread -> NetThread -> SERVER
[Recv Rply]:SERVER -> NetThread -> WebSocketThread -> AnyActivity.Callback

There may be any number of NetThreads at a time

I do not need code, but concepts on what Classes would be efficient and flexible. Also what is the most efficient way to pass the data: Intents; messages; ....?

** I use the term "thread" to mean separate threads that can run concurrently not the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a `Service`. The `Service` will own the websocket `Thread` and will start other `Thread`s to handle individual requests.

Activities call `startService()` to request the `Service` to do something. The calling `Activity` can pass data to the `Service` as extras in the `Intent` that is used in `startService()`. This `Intent` will be passed to method `Service.onStartCommand()`.

To pass data from the `Service` to the `Activity` there are several possibilities (depending on the type and amount of data that need to be returned). One choice is that the `Service` can broadcast the data as "extras" in a broadcast `Intent` using `sendBroadcast()` and the `Activity` can set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the response.

Comment: Thanks, I an going to use one broadcast and callbacks for each request sent.